# Weird issue about IEnumerable<T> collection

Tags: c#, ienumerable, element

I have following code:

```
IEnumerable<TreeItem> rootTreeItems = BuildRootTreeItems();

BuildTreeView(rootTreeItems.ElementAt(0));

private static void BuildTreeView(TreeItem treeItem)
    {
        TreeItem subMenuTreeItem = new TreeItem();
        subMenuTreeItem.Header = "1";

        TreeItem subMenuTreeItem2 = new TreeItem();
        subMenuTreeItem.Header = "2";

        treeItem.TreeItems.Add(subMenuTreeItem);
        treeItem.TreeItems.Add(subMenuTreeItem2);
    }
```

The weird thing is after the BuildTreeView returns, the first element of rootTreeItems doesn't have any children nodes, while it really has when debugging into the BuildTreeView method.

This problem really confused me for quite a long time, any one has any idea? thanks so much.

Comment: Does `BuildRootTreeItems` return a LINQ expression?

Comment: using yield return to return the tree item, but using a parameter which is also IEnumerable<T> type

Comment: Yes, `yield return` will also cause this problem.

Comment: Then what shall I use? just as Enigmativity suggested, using to toList()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're most likely hitting a deferred execution issue with `IEnumerable<>`. The thing to remember is that your `IEnumerable<TreeItem> rootTreeItems` is not a list, instead it is a promise to get a list each and every time it is asked to do so.

So, if `BuildRootTreeItems()` creates the `IEnumerable<TreeItem>` using a LINQ query and it doesn't force the execution of the query using `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` then each time that you use `rootTreeItems` you are re-executing the query inside `BuildRootTreeItems()`

Calling `rootTreeItems.ElementAt(0)` will cause the query to execute. If later you try to call `rootTreeItems.ElementAt(0)` again then you are re-executing the query and getting back a different instance of the first `TreeItem`.

Try changing the first line like so:

```
IEnumerable<TreeItem> rootTreeItems = BuildRootTreeItems().ToArray();
```

This forces the execution and will prevent re-execution later. I'll bet your problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks, man, now I am clearer on what is happening, ToList() helps me solve the issue, but what I am still confused is I only hit rootTreeItems.ElementAt(0) once, how come the children is not able to be added

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility what your BuildRootTreeItems() method returns IEnumerable interface which elements are created via yield statement or as Gabe mentioned in comment above an implementation of IEnumerable which is created via Linq expressions chain containing Select method.

This can lead to recreating elements of IEnumerable on each access to any element from enumeration or iterating via it using Linq expressions or foreach statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would go simplier:

This also could happen if

A) TreeItem is a value type(struct)

B) TreeItem.TreeItems returns a new collection

But correctness of this is difficult to deduct just from code provided.

Comment: 1. TreeItem is not value type

Comment: 2. TreeItems is always the same colloection which is created when class is constructed